# PHP SQL counting number of matches for query

Tags: php, sql, count

How would i go about counting the number of rows that match two variables?

I have a table called: **users**

and fields called: *username* & *referral*

I have another table called: **comments**

and fields called: *comment_username*

This is the situation, I need to fetch the number of referrals with at least 10 comments (rows in the comments' table) that a specific user has referred.

So i was thinking the code should be something like this crude outline.

```
    $username = 'bob';
$validrefferalcount = 0;
function validreferrals($username){

    $referreduser = SQL select * from users where referral='$username';

    foreach ($referreduser)   {

    $numberofcomments = SQL count * from comments where comment_username ='$referreduser';
if ($numberofcomments >= 10){
$validreferralcount = $validreferralcount + 1;
}

    }
return $validreferralcount;
    }
```

I apologize for the bad syntax, etc...

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Well, instead of apologizing, maybe you should fix the bad syntax?

Comment: i dont know exactly how it will look as a end product and i'm just typing what i believe would be the some what correct code.

Comment: What does $referreduser have as a value (the ID of the user, the username of the user) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS c_comments
    FROM users
        JOIN comments ON username = comment_username
    WHERE referral = 'referral'
    GROUP BY username
) t
WHERE t.c_comments > 10;
```

Comment: is the "t" supposed to be there in the second to last line?

Comment: @jjexi - Yes it's supposed to be. t is the SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (*) query result

Comment: Yes, it's an alias for the sub-query.

Answer (score 3):

You should use JOIN in your case. Something like (if I understand correctly)

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users 
   RIGHT JOIN comments ON comments.comment_username = users.username 
   WHERE users.referral = '$username'
```

You can find more information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: close enough :D, i'll fill in the rest

Answer (score 3):

Since my actual post count does not allow for comments yet, some additions to christians answer.

A having clause against the count, so the >= 10 condition is matched would be a good idea

Comment: Sure, that's why I'd hope to post a comment on it instead of another answer ;)